# How to draw an animatable ruler with Quartz2D?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'd like to draw the lines of a simple ruler with Quartz2D, just for practice.

Since I have no idea about doing vector graphics programmatically on the iPhone, maybe someone can point me to a good tutorial to get started?

Comment: The official documentation is quite good, so you'd be best starting with that:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Plamen points out, the [Quartz 2D documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) is worth reading.  Additionally, the course notes [are available online](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip) (VoodooPad format) for my iPhone development course, where I devote an entire class to Quartz 2D drawing.  The [QuartzExamples](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/QuartzExamples.zip) sample application I created shows some more advanced drawing concepts, but Apple's [QuartzDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) sample is a better place to start to see how you can do simple drawing.

As an example of drawing ticks for a ruler, the following is code that I have used to do something similar:

```
NSInteger minorTickCounter = majorTickInterval;
NSInteger totalNumberOfTicks = totalTravelRangeInMicrons / minorTickSpacingInMicrons;
CGFloat minorTickSpacingInPixels = currentHeight / (CGFloat)totalNumberOfTicks;

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [MyView blackColor]);

for (NSInteger currentTickNumber = 0; currentTickNumber < totalNumberOfTicks; currentTickNumber++)
{
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, leftEdgeForTicks + 0.5, round(currentTickNumber * minorTickSpacingInPixels) + 0.5);

    minorTickCounter++;
    if (minorTickCounter >= majorTickInterval)
    {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, round(leftEdgeForTicks + majorTickLength) + 0.5, round(currentTickNumber * minorTickSpacingInPixels) + 0.5);
        minorTickCounter = 0;               
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, round(leftEdgeForTicks + minorTickLength) + 0.5, round(currentTickNumber * minorTickSpacingInPixels) + 0.5);
    }
}

CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

where `currentHeight` is the height of the area to cover, and `[MyView blackColor]` simply returns a CGColorRef representing the color black.

Comment: the code is not clear (as syntax) , please make the example clearer , how you created and sat height for that context ... etc