# Drawing a ruler in objective c iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create a dynamic ruler using code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532805/how-to-draw-an-animatable-ruler-with-quartz2d) of Brad Larson

```
NSInteger majorTickInterval = 5;
    NSInteger totalTravelRangeInMicrons = 1000;
    NSInteger minorTickSpacingInMicrons = 50;
    CGFloat currentHeight = 100;
    int leftEdgeForTicks = 10;
    int majorTickLength = 15;
    int minorTickLength = 10;

    NSInteger minorTickCounter = majorTickInterval;
    NSInteger totalNumberOfTicks = totalTravelRangeInMicrons / minorTickSpacingInMicrons;
    CGFloat minorTickSpacingInPixels = currentHeight / (CGFloat)totalNumberOfTicks;

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

    for (NSInteger currentTickNumber = 0; currentTickNumber < totalNumberOfTicks; currentTickNumber++)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, leftEdgeForTicks + 0.5, round(currentTickNumber * minorTickSpacingInPixels) + 0.5);

        minorTickCounter++;
        if (minorTickCounter >= majorTickInterval)
        {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, round(leftEdgeForTicks + majorTickLength) + 7**.5, round(currentTickNumber * minorTickSpacingInPixels) + 0.5);
            minorTickCounter = 0;               
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, round(leftEdgeForTicks + minorTickLength) + 0.5, round(currentTickNumber * minorTickSpacingInPixels) + 0.5);
        }

    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

But the issue is that it is creating ticks vertically not horizontally as in below screenshot:

[image: screen shot]

While I want to draw a ruler like this:

[image: screenshot2]

Also it is not giving me more than 25 ticks, I have played with the code but still unsuccessful.

Any guidance how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: how wide do you need the ruller to be?

Comment: What did you do "playing around"? It seems trivial to just change the coordinates of the `CGPoint`s. Try to understand what is happening in the code and rewrite it with better variable names.

Comment: Actually I want it to be dynamic because the ruler is to be used to show the video length. Like if video length has increased then the ruler length will be increased too and it will be wider

Comment: Focus on `CGContextMoveToPoint` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint`. There are coordinates for drawing your ruler. Also as @Mundi wrote, try to read it, understand it, it's pretty simple and you can do it very easily.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation, from the top of my head... I think it is important to keep it **readable**.

```
CGFloat leftMargin= 10;
CGFloat topMargin = 10;
CGFloat height = 30;
CGFloat width = 200;
CGFloat minorTickSpace = 10;
int multiple = 5;              // number of minor ticks per major tick
CGFloat majorTickLength = 20;  // must be smaller or equal height, 
CGFloat minorTickLength = 10;  // must be smaller than majorTickLength

CGFloat baseY = topMargin + height;
CGFloat minorY = baseY - minorTickLength;
CGFloat majorY = baseY - majorTickLength;
CGFloat majorTickSpace = minorTickSpace * multiple;

int step = 0;
for (CGFloat x = leftMargin; x <= leftMargin + width, x += minorTickLength) {
   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, baseY);
   CGFloat endY = (step*multiple*minorTickLength  == x) ? majorY : minorY;
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, endY);
   step++;  // step contains the minorTickCount in case you want to draw labels
}
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```